# Ephesoft is not installing libreoffice dependecy

Tags: libreoffice, ephesoft

Im working on ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS and i need to integrate ephesoft 4.0.2.0 to alfresco community so i have to install ephesoft.

While im installing i stack in a point that it can´t install its libreoffice dependency, i first deleted the libreoffice coming in my OS but realize that was not the problem, then i installed another one and again that was not the problem, so i don´t know what to do, the ephesoft installation can not move foward because of it.

Please if there is anyone who can help me with it, I will be gratefull.

Att, MGM

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and try a lot of things and then found out that 16.04 is not supported by ephesoft, only 14.04 and 14.10 work.